# The convergence of the power series $\sum \limits^{\infty }_{n=1}a_{n}(x-2)^{n}$ for various $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I would ask for help on how to solve this problem more specifically to know how to test whether a given $x$ converges in a power series. I would appreciate your insights.

> Of the power series $\sum \limits^{\infty }_{n=1}a_{n}(x-2)^{n}$ , it is known that $x = -3$ converges and diverges at $x = 9$.
>
> What can be said about the convergence of the series at $x = 4$ and $x = -7$?
>
> Can you guarantee that the series converges at $x = 8$?

Answer (score 3):

The radius of convergence is between 5 and 7. That is all we can know. So at $x = 4$ the series converges and at $x = -7$ not. Nothing can be said about $x = 8$.